# 34401A Remote Measurement Time

Tags: multimeter, matlab, data-acquisition

I am using an HP 34401A as an ADC for data acquisition. I am triggering the device within a 'for' loop in MATLAB, so that I can synchronize the measurement with a separate device. I am able to collect a measurement, but the measurement time seems very slow, at about 0.5 s.

My setup goes like this: I set up the digital multimeter (dmm) per the datasheet using

```
dmm = serial('COM3', 'BaudRate', 9600, 'DataBits', 8, ...
    'StopBits', 1, 'Parity', 'No', 'FlowControl', 'software', ...
    'Terminator', 'LF');
fopen(dmm);
fprintf(dmm, 'SYSTem:REMote');
```

Then, within my 'for' loop, I take a sample using:

```
fprintf(dmm, 'MEAS?')
fscanf(dmm)
```

The above two lines of code take ~0.5 seconds to execute. I have tried turning off the display on the multimeter using `fprintf(dmm, 'DISP 0')`, and I have tried consulting the datasheet for other improvements, but nothing improves my measurement time of ~0.5 s per sample. I note that the datasheet specifies that the device "requires approximately 20 ms of set-up time after you send a command to change the 'wait for trigger' state", but I see no reason to expect anything much longer than this. Is there a way to improve my measurement time within my 'for' loop?

Comment: What is your integration time setting? There are trade offs between noise, mains-frequency rejection and resolution, and speed. As there would be with any data acquisition system.

Comment: Chapter 7 "Measurement Tutorial" in the manual, section "Making High-Speed DC and Resistance Measurements", says "For maximum reading speed, turn autozero off. This will more than double your reading speeds for dc voltage, resistance, and dc current functions." If that's any help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing sufficient details about yout setup, I think there are a couple of notes that could be taken int account (some of them could not apply):

**MATLAB SIDE**

**1. Trigger Command:** In the HP 34401A manual, I didn't find the a trigger command named `MEAS?`, but I found there only the `MEASure?` one. Please, confirm this.

**2. Flow Control** You have been used the option `software` for the property `FlowControl` in `serial()` function. It seems that multimeter accepts only `hardware` flow control (based on `RTS/CTS` signals in your cable) as comm. handshaking method. Please, confirm this.

**3. Termination sequence and Timeout**: According the figure below, the communication protocol used by that multimeter is based on text rather than binary (like many others low speed lab equipment and also in AT commands, for example). In RS-232 mode, the command/data sequences are terminated with the pair `CR-NL` (*carriage return* followed by *new line*; the latter also called `LF` or *line feed*) for both, single and multiple readings. Since your code uses only use a single `LF` character as a terminator, this ends up not being a problem.

[image]

You can configure the `Timeout` property to be the maximum time in seconds to wait to complete a read or write operation. If it's not specified, the default value is 10 seconds (I think it's your setting). It has already been reported that, in an event of timeout, a message is shown, something like *Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached..*. As you are receiving data in 0.5 s intervals, this ends up not being a problem, too.

**4. Alternative modes:** There are others forms to utilize the `serial` object, including *callbacks* for receiving and `fread()` with  binary data, for example (even for decoding text data - in this case the `CR-NL` pair should be parsed in code). Of course, that only  would be justifed in higher speeds.

**5. Future compatibility:** The manufacturer has warned that object `serial` should have been removed in release R2021a, being replaced to `serialport` interface. Just for future adaptation.

**MULTIMETER SIDE**

**6. RS-232 interface speed:** This multimeter operates in a maximum 9600 bps. Nothing to do here.

**7. Trigger Source / Trigger Delay**:
You haven't mentioned in question, what's the source trigger in use. Through the command `TRIGger:SOURce` is possible to set the valid options, which `BUS` (software),  `IMMediate` (default) and `EXTernal`. From what I've understood, it seems necessary previously to set the option `BUS` before starting a trigger with `MEASure?` command. Note that the figure below seems to show an inverse order, but the text in Chapter 3 - Triggering, confirms the sequence I've described. Also, if you don't specify a `Trigger Delay` (range 0-3600 seconds) between the trigger signal and each sample that follows (in order to allow the input to settle), the equipment selects a default one , which value is automatic (depending on function, range, integration time, and ac filter adjust). An inappropriate setting here could contribute to that 0.5 s interval you noticed. Then, you could review these settings for your exact environment.

[image]

**8. Samples per Trigger:**
By default, the multimeter takes one reading (or sample) each time it
receives a trigger from the selected trigger source (if the multimeter is
in the `wait-for-trigger state`). I think you are using one sample per trigger, but that could be increased (up to 50000). The following commands put the multimeter in *wait-for-trigger* state: `MEASure?` (please, see my note **1**), `READ?` and `INITiate`.

**9. Integration Time**: Is the period during which the multimeter’s analog-to digital (A/D) converter samples the input signal for a measurement.
`Integration time` affects the measurement resolution. This parameter is specified in number of power line cycles (NPLCs).The choices are 0.02, 0.2, 1, 10, or 100 power line cycles (default is 10). Then, the range should be \$333.3\mu s\$ - \$166.7 ms \space 60 Hz\$. Finally, an inappropriate setting here could contribute to that 0.5 s interval you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

To speed the measurement up you could decrease the resolution.  At high resolution the 34401 is not particularly fast.  That may not meet your requirements though.